# Android how to emoji into Logcat prints?

Tags: android, android-logcat

I will like to see emojis on my logcat print, I think thay may help to see logs.

Some example is [github emoji](http://www.emoji-cheat-sheet.com/) that enabled emojis.

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

1. On MacOS position the cursor to the place to want to insert the emoji.
2. Use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> +  <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> to access emoji list.
3. Double-click the emoji you'd like to use and it'll be inserted where you left your cursor.

Comment: This answer has absolutely nothing to do with the question!!!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not certain, but I don't think it is possible to display emoji on Logcat prints because it would require a charset update.

There's an issue posted on the [android project page](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=174216) requiring it (it's really recent from the time of your post).

Maybe in the future we'll see it, I sure hope so.

Comment: I posted the issue :P

Comment: Hahaha that's nice. Anyways, you could try showing emojis via Toasts or Dialogs using external libraries, but that's just a wild guess.

Answer (score 1):

On your string message, just add the emoji, and when you run your application they will be shown in your Logcat messages. On Windows 10 you can type Windows logo key + . (period). The emoji keyboard will appear.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-keyboard-tips-and-tricks-588e0b72-0fff-6d3f-aeee-6e5116097942